# How to update an table in oracle db using oledbconnection from asp.net c# code

Tags: c#, oracle11g, oledbconnection

I am trying to update an table in oracle 11g database from c# code using an oledbconnection.  The query formation is ok and then hangs at execute.  No error or exception is thrown.  Its like an endless loop. Select and insert query are working fine but update fails.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. If db was connected to multiple tools like sqldeveloper, sqlplus. Db was lockedwith respect to the first session.  Rest of the connection has no permission to perform crud

I have connected the db in sql developer tool. On the other hand I have tried to perform the crud from my project via code. Since the db was connected to sql developer prior to my project the db was locked to perform the crud operation.

Once the another session on sql developer was closed i was able to perform the crud operations from my code.